# Mapping 2d int array to 2d char array (filein to fileout) in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, fopen, fclose

This is a question from cprimerplus 6th ed. I am trying to open a file containing a 20x30 block of space separated numbers with values between 0-9 and print it in another file with those values corresponding to chars of increasing darkness.

Here is my code, but I keep getting segmentation fault (core dumped) and the output file is empty. I tried the code from the solution manual and while it is different than mine I still get a segmentation fault. Can someone help me find out what is causing this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 30
#define LEVELS 10
const char trans[LEVELS + 1] = " .-=+xX$%#"; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int row, col;
int picdata[ROWS][COLS];
FILE *datafile;
FILE *outfile;

if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usgae: %s [data] [outfile]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if ((datafile = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s.\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) 
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) 
        fscanf(datafile, "%d", &picdata[row][col]);

if (ferror(datafile)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading data file %s.\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (fclose(datafile) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file %s.\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if ((outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s.\n", argv[2]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        fprintf(outfile, "%c", trans[picdata[row][col]]);
    }
    fputc('\n', outfile); 
}
if (fclose(outfile) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file %s.\n", argv[2]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: A segmentation fault implies an invalid memory access of some sort.  Have you tried running your program in a debugger to determine where the error is occurring?  Or even added `printf` statements to see how far the program gets before crashing?

Comment: The bug might be here `trans[picdata[row][col]]` please make sure that the array index for this is always between 0-9 are sure you are not doing any array out of bound access? Since we don't see the file from where the data is read we can just suspect this

Comment: It probably comes from reading too far into the trans array (nb that you don't have to give it a size as it's fixed at compile time). Add a check on picdata being between 0 and 10 before using it as an index into trans, and tell us about what you get.

Comment: @Gopi you beat me coz I'm on a phone ;)

Comment: Lol problem solved. When I actually went and checked the data file the array only had half the rows it was supposed to; the array was split between two pages in my pdf since it was at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: And if it's a text file, you might want to open it as such: "rt" instead of "rb", it can skip EoL properly.

Comment: On another note, though, I did add printf's all over and even with one right after the FILE declarations the statement did not print and I still got segmentation fault. Shouldn't it have at least run until the fscanf?

Comment: @SoLost Please check return value of `fscanf()` like `if(fscanf(...) ==1)` then this way you can check where exactly you are going wrong